# Content Type in Document Library not working - 32-bit apps in 64-bit SP environment

Tags: office-365, content-type

I have a 64-bit machine.  SharePoint 2013 on premise is 64-bit. Office 365, IE 11 and SharePoint Designer are all 32-bit. I added a content type for a document library and add a template.docx to it.  When I select File>New Document>Create a new document (which should pop up the template, I get the error below.

Is this because I have 32-bit apps on a 64-bit machine?  Or because I have 32-bit apps on a 64-bit implementation of SharePoint 2013 on prem?  Or is it something else. My IE 11 is 32-bit and I can't install the 64-bit version because all of Office 365 is 32-bit.  That's another error that I get when I try to install the 64-bit version of IE.

Thanks!

[image: Error when using content type in a document library.]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont have the office web apps installed on your server since it tries to open in your local office programs instead of going via the web apps. 
Using the web apps gives you a bit more flexibility when it comes to the users computer, but on the other hand it will give you one extra step when you create a document if you dont use the web apps.

Why cant you install the 64-bit office?

This will answer your question:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx
[image]